# Using terminal on mac as interactive interpreter

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to use mac's terminal to debug and test my python programs but I always get an error.

Can anyone help with this do I need to write something different on mac? Below is what I have written and the error I got. I have tried with a few different ways e.g. importing from and other files but the same error message keeps appearing.

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python -i notebook.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -i notebook.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: you are trying to run a pyton CLI command within python interpreter. 
Exit python inerpreter via CTRL+D and run this command in terminal

Comment: i did run it in terminal. I went in terminal typed python3. then typed what i have shown above and always get the same error whatever i try to do

Comment: Don't run python3 first, run the command @ruohola gives in his answer in a bare terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run

```
python3 -i notebook.py
```

straight in the terminal. **Do not** first open the Python interpreter with the `python3` command.

Comment: When i do that it says no file or directory

Comment: Should i be saving it in a particular place?

Comment: You need to run the command from the same directory where `notebook.py` is.